# Using ViewData and ControllerContext in an external service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following piece of code that works within a controller.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                    viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                        ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

I'd like to move it to an external service for reuse, but cannot resolve ViewData or ControllerContext.  Aside from changing the signature to be static, what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `ViewData` and `ControllerContext` to the method as arguments.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model, ViewData viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext)
{

}
```